# Running single application on a virtual environment

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual

I don't know whether this is possible but would like to give it a go and see if someone knows something about it.

I work with applications that fix phones and sometime it happens that driver of one application can conflict with another.

I was wondering if is possible to create multiple virtual machines (lightweight) that can host a single software and just drivers related to it so I can isolate the environment from other software.

Let's say I want to create one virtual machine that when I turn on, it will only open a samsung app,it will have it's own drivers, dedicated small space and device connection ability.
I want to do this with multiple software.

I heard of virtual machines like virtual box but thought they are too heavy for running a single app.
How about docker or something similar? can they work for this purpose?

NOTE: I want to run software that run on win 7 only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Docker runs only on Linux;  you will need sort of "full virtualization" software to run it on Windows!

I know of several VM software for Windows, but all of them are rather heavy for running a single app.  Also, I think you need separate Windows license for each "guest" ("child") Windows installation.

- http://www.zdnet.com/article/the-best-and-cheapest-ways-to-get-windows-and-linux-for-virtual-machines/